# When does contraction in sup norm implies pointwise contraction?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

I was wondering about the following question :

Suppose I have a contraction mapping $\tau$ for a bounded continuous function in supremum norm.

$$ \beta \cdot ||u-v||_{\infty}\geq ||\tau(u)-\tau(v)||_{\infty}  $$

for $\beta \in (0,1)$. This is easily attained if I use Blackwell's sufficient condition.  However, what I'm interested in is if

$$ \beta \cdot |u(x)-v(x)| \geq |(\tau(u)(x)-\tau(v)(x)|  $$

for any $x \in [0,1]$. In this case, is there any sufficient conditions that I can use to show this pointwise contraction?

Comment: While your complete failure to specify what spaces you are talking about leaves me wondering about certain aspects, it seems pretty clear that the condition you are interested in is just a restriction of the original condition to some curve. So why is this a problem? If you get the top relationship, the bottom one immediately follows from it.

Comment: Hi thank you for leaving the comment. I am still struglling to learn how to post a question with rigorous notations. 

The space is real valued, bounded, continuous function space defined on $x \in [0,1]$. This is a complete metric space. And I thought the bottom directly implies the top but not the other way round. Can you be more detailed on that part? Thanks

Comment: Okay, so now the notation $\tau \circ u(x)$ or $\tau \circ v(x)$ do not make sense. $u,v : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$, while $\tau : C([0,1]) \to C([0.1])$. Since the domain of $\tau$ is entirely different from the codoman of $u, v$, you cannot compose $\tau$ with $u$ or $v$. What you actually mean might be written as $\tau(u)(x)$ or $\tau(u)|_x$ or $\tau|_u(x)$. All of these mean the function $\tau(u) \in C([0,1])$ evaluated at $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed it that way!

Comment: The reason I thought the first relation implied the second is because of the compositions. I took $u(x), v(x)$ to be curves into the then-unknown domain of $\tau$ rather than evaluations of $u, v$ at a point $x$ in their domains. As it is now, the second condition is a much more stringent restriction on the behavior of $\tau$ than the first. It would take another fairly severe condition on $\tau$ to imply it. For example $\tau$ being linear.